# How can I access the outer loop context value in inner loop section in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates, nested-for-loop

In my case, I want to access the context value which is present in the outer for loop and use(print) that value in the inner for loop section. There are two context values one for the outer loop and the other one is for the inner loop.
here is my template logic. when the condition becomes false it did not print the values that belong to the outer-loop context variable(else part of if statement not working).

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        {% for x in queryset %}<!--outerloop-->
        
                
            <div id="collapse{{ forloop.counter }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    
                    
                    <div>
                        <form action="tobeupdated" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                            
                            
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <label>Q- <input type="text" id="ques" name="ques" value="{{x.question.question}}" readonly></label><br><br>
                            <img src="{{x.question.image}}" alt="" srcset="" width="700"><br><br>


                        
            
                            {% for q2 in queryset2 %}<!--innerloop-->
                                {% if q2.option_id == x.option_id %}
                                    <label>A- <input type="text" id="op1" name="op1" value="{{q2.option.option1}}" readonly><br><br>
                                    <img src="{{q2.option1_img}}" alt="" srcset="" width="400"><br><br>
                                    <label>B- <input type="text" id="op2" name="op2" value="{{q2.option.option2}}" readonly><br><br>
                                    <img src="{{q2.option2_img}}" alt="" srcset="" width="400"><br><br>

                                    <label>C- <input type="text" id="op3" name="op3" value="{{q2.option.option3}}" readonly><br><br>
                                    <img src="{{q2.option3_img}}" alt="" srcset="" width="400"><br><br>

                                    <label>D- <input type="text" id="op4" name="op4" value="{{q2.option.option4}}" readonly><br><br>
                                    <img src="{{q2.option4_img}}" alt="" srcset="" width="400"><br><br>
                                {% else %}
                                    
                                    <label>A- <input type="text" id="op1" name="op1" value="{{x.option.option1}}" readonly><br><br>

                                    <label>B- <input type="text" id="op2" name="op2" value="{{x.option.option2}}" readonly><br><br>

                                    <label>C- <input type="text" id="op3" name="op3" value="{{x.option.option3}}" readonly><br><br>

                                    <label>D- <input type="text" id="op4" name="op4" value="{{x.option.option4}}" readonly><br><br>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}

                            <label>Correct Ans- <input type="text" id="ans" name="ans" value="{{x.correct_ans}}" readonly><br><br>
                            <input type="hidden" id="dlevel"  name="dlevel" value="{{x.question.difficulty}}">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="" checked>
                            <label>{{x.question.difficulty}}</label>
                            <!-- <input type="submit" id="update" value="Update" /> -->
                         <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="qid" value="{{x.question.id}}" >Edit</button>
                         <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="delete_qid" value="{{x.question.id}}" >Delete</button>


                        </form>

                        
                    </div>
                    <!--Toogle Button-->
                    
                                   
                </div>
            </div>

            {{x.question.id}}
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->

  

            </div>
    
        </div>



        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Any suggestions regarding this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you please reduce your code to show only the core of your problem? I thinks its a matter of simple `with` statement but I will look into it when the code's more readable

Comment: @quqa123 question updated

Comment: still can't see (reproduce) your problem everything seems okay. I dont really know what is not "printing" but if you mean `{{ x.option.option1 }}` it probably means that `x` doesnt have the `option.option1` so the  variable silently fails and is set to `None`. Please read your quesiton carefully and understand that It's not clear what youre trying to do, there is code that is of no use to helpers and there is no output (rendered html) so we can't really see whats wrong